# Why does my scope update my factory and my factory update my scope when it should not?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

Why does `$scope.events.push(data);` update both the scope and the factory?

Why does `EventFactory.setEvent(data);` update both the factory and the scope?

Summary:

```
$scope.events.push(data); //should only update scope but also updates factory
EventFactory.setEvent(data); //should only update factory but also updates scope
```

If I don't uncomment one of those lines then I get the same effect as doing:

```
$scope.events.push(data);
$scope.events.push(data);
```

or

```
EventFactory.setEvent(data);
EventFactory.setEvent(data);
```

Basically `$scope.events.push(data);` and `EventFactory.setEvent(data);` update both the factory and the scope.

I want `$scope.events.push(data);` to only update the scope.

I want `EventFactory.setEvent(data);` to only update the factory.

app.js (contains the factory)

```
...
app.factory("EventFactory", function($http){

    var events = [];

    var init = function(){
        return $http.get("api/events", {cache:true})
        .then(
            function(response){
                events = response.data;
                return response.data;
            });
    };

    var getEvents = function(){
        return events;
    };

    var setEvent = function(data){
        events.push(data);
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        getEvents: getEvents,
        setEvent: setEvent
    }
});
...
```

EventListCtrl.js (controller)

```
angular.module("EventListCtrl", []).controller("EventListController", function($scope, EventFactory, socket){

    $scope.events = [];

    EventFactory.init().then(function(events){
        $scope.events = events;
    });

    socket.on("event created", function(data){
        $scope.events.push(data); // should only update scope but updates factory as well
        EventFactory.setEvent(data); // should only update factory but updates scope as well
    });
});
```

I have tested the code and the socket is not the problem, maybe some binding has taken place that I have no understanding of as yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: What is the `socket` dependency you are passing in?

Comment: angular-socket-io from bfford https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are making `$scope.events = events` in your controller instead of `$scope.events = angular.copy(events);`

*(you could instead make the copy in your service, which would be more DRY)*

More plainly put, this is happening because you are making object references; not object clones/copies.  *(Arrays are technically objects)*

Comment: Thanks Cory I did not know this, this was the issue indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending socket event of "Event created" to others and probably receiving it yourself also so your scope also updates

More over

> All services in angularjs are singletons

And you have only one copy of the service everywhere and thats how it works when you change some thing in factory it will be updated elsewhere too

Comment: Thanks A.B for taking the time to reply but my issue was what Cory has posted.

Answer (score 0):

In EventListCtrl controller you are doing the shallow copy by doing:

```
 $scope.events = events;
```

where both of the objects are having the same reference.

To make deep copy out of it, angular provides us copy() method:

```
angular.copy(source, [destination]);
source: The source that will be used to make a copy. Can be any type, including primitives, null, and undefined
destination(optional): Destination into which the source is copied. If provided, must be of the same type as source.
```

In your case it should be:

```
$scope.events = angular.copy(events);
```